# 301 redirect from high DA sites to current site

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, blackhat

Currently, a high DA site is going to be decommissioned. Although separate entities/organization, but related topics, is it advisable to purchase the high DA site just to 301 redirect to the current low DA site?

Everytime we search for a few keywords pertaining the topic, the one page of the high DA's site is bound to rank first on SERPs. Do you think we should purchase the domain name, and redirect just that particular page to our current site?

is it considered a black hat practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that is a blackhat practice because it depends on why you would redirect this domain to your own site.

You can find types of response in [this article](http://searchengineland.com/do-links-from-expired-domains-count-with-google-17811). Extract:

> **1. Buying Expired Domains: Don’t Expect Credit**
>
> Have you picked up a domain that was once owned by someone, not
>   through buying it directly from them but because it had expired and
>   went back into the common pool of domains for purchase by anyone?
>   That’s an expired domain – and chances are, the backlinks aren’t going
>   to pass credit according to Matt’s statement.
>
> **2. Buying Domains & Redirecting Links: Probably No Credit**
>
> Did you see a tasty domain and think it would be nice to get it, in
>   order to obtain its links for a different site, such a redirecting
>   them? Sounds like there’s a good chance that Google is going to notice
>   the purchase date, take note of the redirection as well and decide
>   those “historic” links shouldn’t count. What about if you just paid
>   someone to keep the domain going under their name but closed down any
>   existing content and point to another location? Might work; then
>   again, Google might note the change, the oddity of one site to
>   completely point at another, and it might be that the links won’t
>   count.
>
> **3. Buying Domain & Running Web Site As Usual: Credit Likely**
>
> Did you buy a web site from someone else and are maintaining the
>   business on that site as normal? Despite the fact that your domain
>   name registration will have changed, since the site is carrying on as
>   usual, there seems to be a good chance that link credit will continue
>   as normal.
>
> **4. Getting Domains Through Acquisition: Credit Likely**
>
> Have a domain that changes hands, due to a company acquisition –
>   company A buys company B? You should be OK, thought it’s unclear how
>   Google tells the difference here from an ordinary transfer. And no,
>   Google wouldn’t share more on how they can tell the difference.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The purpose of buying the domain is because it's of the same niche. Especially when their pages ranked higher than ours in SERPs (first on the page!). When we heard that it is going to be decommissioned, we thought this would be a good opportunity to purchase their domain, and do a 301 redirect on their top page to link to one of our pages.

I read from "http://www.shoutmeloud.com/301-redirect-passes-page-rank.html" that it would be considered a blackhat practice because then, anyone could just purchase high domains and 301 redirect! No effort on their part!

Comment: I told you the theory (what Matt Cutts from Google says). In relation to your words, you most probably in the second category; therefore **probably no credit**. This is not the perfect answer but I can't do better for you. This kind of question always generates people reactions like do it! or don't do it! In any case, if you buy this domain, make sure its actual visitors won't be lost when redirecting to your site.